# Possible to have a QCompleter-like appearance without using a QCompleter?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5, qcompleter

Long story short, I already have the things that I need to display (for a qlineedit) in a list. But there are some additional information that I need to display in the auto-complete box, that messes up the QCompleter since I use its setModel method to update what it displays (so the additional information that I put into the setModel method messes with the completion rule of the QCompleter) So I need a QCompleter-like display underneath a QLineEdit. Is there anyway I can make that happen?

```
#The method TopProducts(text) -> returns a list of strings with the format 
#"manufacturer - model number - description" (picks three products based on the given text)

#in __init__ somewhere:
self.nameEdit = QLineEdit()
self.completer = QCompleter()
self.nameEdit.setCompleter(self.completer)
self.nameEdit.textEdited.connect(self.suggest)
self.model = QStringListModel()

def suggest(self,text):
    stringList = TopProducts(text)
    self.model.setStringList(stringList)
    self.completer.setModel(self.model)
```

Comment: explain yourself better, I do not understand what you want, it would be very helpful if you endorse an image indicating what you want.

Comment: Do you mean a popup that is shown with the QCompleter ?, Do you want to show something similar to what SO offers for the tags? QCompleter is not a widget.

Comment: Sorry I am not being clear, it is just hard to explain. As you can see in the picture I linked above, there are more products that starts with "Sta" then the one that is actually shown in the box. However, that is the only one that is shown in the box because its manufacturer also starts with "Sta". I need the QCompleter to ignore the first word in the string list that I supply.

Comment: You could show a code that reproduces your error to understand you better, that's what I call [mcve]

Comment: Does each element of the list that you pass to QCompleter have only 2 words ?, and you want me to filter it only by the second word?

Comment: The element of the list contains a lot of words but the item name is guaranteed to be the second word in the list, as the first word is the manufacturer and the third word is where the description starts. I want it to only auto complete the second word and ignore the first word while still displaying everything (manufacturer, item name, description)  inside the auto complete box.

Comment: According to what I read in each suggestion to three parts: manufacturer - model number - description, which of those parts do you want to be used for the flitro ?, only model number, or model number and description.

Comment: Only the model number.

Comment: try with my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A suitable solution is to create a custom model that has roles for each manufacturer, model number and description, so you can use the `completionRole` property of `QCompleter` and only filter it by model number.

By default the selected role text is displayed, so that we do not have that inappropriate behavior we will overwrite `pathFromIndex()` to return the `Qt::DisplayRole` role:

```
class ProductModel(QAbstractListModel):
    ManufacturerRole, ModelNumberRole, DescriptionRole = range(Qt.UserRole, Qt.UserRole + 3)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QAbstractListModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self._products = []

    def addProduct(self, product):
        self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())
        self._products.append(product)
        self.endInsertRows()

    def removeProduct(self, model_number, manufacturer):
        selecteds = filter(lambda product: product['manufacturer'] == manufacturer and product["modelNumber"] == model_number, 
            self._products)
        for selected in selecteds:
            row = self._products.index(selected)
            self.beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), row, row)
            self._products.pop(row)
            self.endRemoveRows()

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._products)

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if 0 <= index.row() < self.rowCount():
            product = self._products[index.row()]
            if role == ProductModel.ManufacturerRole:
                return product["manufacturer"]
            elif role == ProductModel.ModelNumberRole:
                return product["modelNumber"]
            elif role == ProductModel.DescriptionRole:
                return product["description"]
            elif role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                return "{} {} {}".format(*product.values())

class ProductCompler(QCompleter):
    def pathFromIndex(self, index):
        return index.data()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    le = QLineEdit()
    completer = ProductCompler(le)
    le.setCompleter(completer)
    model = ProductModel()
    completer.setModel(model)
    completer.setCompletionRole(ProductModel.ModelNumberRole)

    model.addProduct({"manufacturer": "StarTech", "modelNumber": "STANDOFF122", "description": "description"})
    model.addProduct({"manufacturer": "StarTrek", "modelNumber": "STANDOFF111", "description": "description"})
    model.addProduct({"manufacturer": "StackOverFlow", "modelNumber": "STANDOFF100", "description": "description"})
    model.addProduct({"manufacturer": "StarTech", "modelNumber": "ABCSTANDOFF122", "description": "description"})
    model.addProduct({"manufacturer": "StarTrek", "modelNumber": "ABCSTANDOFF111", "description": "description"})
    model.addProduct({"manufacturer": "StackOverFlow", "modelNumber": "DFSTANDOFF100", "description": "description"})

    model.removeProduct("STANDOFF111", "StarTrek")

    le.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works! To delete a product what should I do?

Comment: @Steve What parameter do you want to pass to remove a product? In other words, which of the three fields is unique.

Comment: I would have to pass in the model number and the manufacturer to remove an entry since the model number can be the same.